# Axon aggregate reference

Tags: domain-driven-design, axon, aggregateroot

In `DDD` we model the domain using several aggregates (root + entities). One such aggregate or entity can hold a reference to another aggregate root through its `id`.

In `axon`, I see the concept of aggregates and member entities, but I do not see the notion of references to other aggregates.

What am I missing? Or is this not possible in `axon`?

Answer (score 2):

It works the same, you can hold the reference of another aggregate throught its `aggregateId` (String/UUID/Whatever).

I wish I could provide more insights to you but your question is rather vague =)

Comment: Let's say I have